# SQL variable Concatenation

Tags: sql, sql-server-2000

I have a SQL Server 2000 stored procedure that accepts a number of input variables.

I need to concatenate two of them (both nvarchar) and pass that to another stored procedure.  At the moment it looks like this:

```
EXEC usp_SProc @Variable1, @Variable2 + ' ' + @Variable3
```

However, when this is executed I receive the error:

```
Incorrect syntax near '+'
```

I receive the same error if I try this in a simple SELECT statement.  Can anyone guide me in the right direction?

Thanks

Comment: Filip, Mitch - Awesome, thanks for posting an answer so quickly!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
DECLARE @combinedVar nvarchar(size)   -- where size is your expected datatype size
SET @combinedVar  = @Variable2 + ' ' + @Variable3 

EXEC usp_SProc @Variable1, @combinedVar
```

Answer (score 3):

SQL Server does not allow expressions in EXEC. You have to declare new variable, set concatenated value and execute stored procedure.

```
DECLARE @V_Concatenated NVARCHAR(200)
SET @V_Concatenated = @Variable2 + ' ' + @Variable3
EXEC usp_SProc @Variable1, @V_Concatenated
```

Just don't forget to set @V_Concatenated length to appropriate value.